# Issues with bootloader

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I am in the process of learning Assembly, and I tried writing my own bootloader. It works fine on VirtualBox , but it doesn't work on a actual PC.
On pc 'Hello World!' doesn't get printed.

This is the code is use:

```
BITS 16
ORG 0x7C00

jmp boot_sector

;------------------------------

OEMLabel            db "FLOPPYDR"
BytesPerSector      dw 512
SectorsPerCluster   db 1
ReservedForBoot     dw 1
NumberOfFats        db 2
RootDirEntries      dw 224
LogicalSectors      dw 2880
MediumByte          db 0xF0
SectorsPerFat       dw 9
SectorsPerTrack     dw 18
Sides               dw 2
HiddenSectors       dd 0
LargeSectors        dd 0
DriveNo             dw 0
Signature           db 41
VolumeID            dd 0x00
VolumeLabel         db "FLOPPYDRIVE"
FileSystem          db "FAT12"

;##############################
          boot_sector:
;##############################

  mov ax, 0x0000            ; Set up the stack
  mov ss, ax                ; Is this done correctly?
  mov sp, 0x7C00            ; (I dont quite understand)

  int 0x10                  ; Set video mode

  int 0x13                  ; Reset the drive

  mov ah, 0x02              ; Read more sectors
  mov al, 2                 ; Read two extra sectors,
  mov bx, main_sector       ; starting from the second.
  mov ch, 0                 ;
  mov cl, 2                 ; dl has been set already (?)
  mov dh, 0                 ;
  int 0x13                  ;

  mov [bootdev], dl         ; Store original dl in bootdev

  jmp main_sector           ; Go to the main sector (0x200 I think)

  times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0 ; Fill in the rest of the sector with 0s
  dw 0xAA55                 ; and 0xAA55 at the end for signature

;##############################
          main_sector:
;##############################

jmp Start

;------------------------------

bootdev db 0
msg db 'Hello World!', 10, 13, 0

;------------------------------

print_string:
  mov ah, 0x0E
  mov bh, 0
  cmp al, 0
  jne .loop
  mov bl, 0x0F
  .loop:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .end
    int 0x10
    jmp .loop
  .end:
    ret

;------------------------------

  Start:
    mov si, msg
    call print_string
    hlt

    times 512 - ($ - main_sector) db 0
```

I've also commented in some questions, but these are not my main question (well, maybe me not knowing the answer causes the problem). Why doesn't this work on a real PC?

To compile I use `nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin` and to create a virtual floppydisk file I use `mkfile 1474560 floppy.flp`

Then I open up `floppy.flp` using HexEdit and replace the first 64 lines (0x00 - 0x3F) with the content of the `boot.bin` file (opened using HexEdit).

```
E9 38 00 46 4C 4F 50 50 59 44 52 00 02 01 01 00
02 E0 00 40 0B F0 09 00 12 00 02 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 29 00 00 00 00 46 4C 4F 50 50
59 44 52 49 56 45 46 41 54 31 32 B8 00 00 8E D0
BC 00 7C CD 10 CD 13 B4 02 B0 02 BB 00 7E B5 00
B1 02 B6 00 CD 13 88 16 03 7E E9 A3 01 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 AA <-- End of first sector
E9 24 00 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21
0A 0D 00 B4 0E B7 00 3C 00 75 02 B3 0F AC 3C 00
74 04 CD 10 EB F7 C3 BE 04 7E E8 E6 FF F4 00 00 (The rest is just 0's).
```

This is the Terminal when I burn `floppy.flp` to the USB drive:

```
Last login: Wed Sep 23 12:10:48 on ttys000
MacBook-Air:~ sasha$ cd ~/Desktop
MacBook-Air:Desktop sasha$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 8CD6A846-395D-4C97-A5DE-0A7ABA9F1C99
                                 Unencrypted
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *17.1 MB    disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Flash Player            17.1 MB    disk2s2
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            FLOPPYDRIVE            *1.0 GB     disk3
MacBook-Air:Desktop sasha$ diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk3
Unmount of all volumes on disk3 was successful
MacBook-Air:Desktop sasha$ sudo dd bs=512 if=floppy.flp of=/dev/disk3
Password:
2880+0 records in
2880+0 records out
1474560 bytes transferred in 0.843982 secs (1747146 bytes/sec)
MacBook-Air:Desktop sasha$
```

Comment: I wrote an answer recently with `general tips on developing a bootloader` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942) . Points 1,2,3 and their solution may hep you.

Comment: In your case you may need to ALSO align your disk  data structure by putting a `NOP` instruction right *after* `jmp boot_sector`

Comment: Specific to your case _ES_ and _DS_ will be a big factor. _DS_ is needed for the `lodsb` and a proper _ES_ will be needed for int 0x13 since it requires a full address in _ES:BX_ for the disk buffer. Since you use `lodsb` you should clear the direction flag with `cld` after you set up your stack so that `lodsb` is guaranteed to increments _SI_ after each execution.

Comment: Rather than use hexedit you can use `dd` to overwrite the first 1024 byes and keep the rest intact. Try `dd if=boot.bin of=floppy.flp bs=512 count=2 conv=notrunc` . This should open up floppy.flp write 2 512 byte sectors containing the 1024 bytes from boot.bin without truncating the file (conv=notrunc)

Comment: As for asking if you are setting your stack correctly. There is nothing wrong with it. Your instructions effectively set up a a stack that grows downward from `0x0000::0x7C00` just below the area occupied by your bootloader. That leaves about 27k (`0x7C00`-`0x1000`) of stack space (4k) is plenty for BIOS calls and your current code. The first `0x1000` of memory are generally for interrupt table/bios data area etc.

Comment: @MichaelPetch This is all very helpful, you seem to know your Assembly well, thank you for responding, I will let you know if you helped me solve the problem later.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It most certainly worked, thank you again!

Comment: I'll write up a specific answer with all this information a bit later, including the tip about `dd`. Did you happen to try out the `dd` trick to avoid hexedit? I am curious if it worked on OS/X (it should have)

Comment: @MichaelPetch It worked like a charm :)

Comment: Then I shall add that tidbit to my answer.Someone else who comes across this question may benefit from it.

Comment: I have produced a proper answer to your question, and while I was writing it I noticed another subtle bug with your Disk Reset code. You might want to check that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've [written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942) about bootloaders at some length recently on Stackoverflow. Most issues that involve the situation where it works on one emulator or VM but not on another (or physical hardware) usually come down to making false assumptions about the state of the segment registers when the BIOS jumps to your code. Under some emulators the segment registers may have more sane values in them, but that usually isn't the case. From my previous answer I had these two tips that seem to apply here:

1. When the BIOS jumps to your code you can't rely on *DS*,*ES*,*SS*,*SP* registers having valid or expected values. They should be set up appropriately when your bootloader starts.
2. The direction flag used by `lodsb`, `movsb` etc could be either set or cleared. If the direction flag is set improperly *SI*/*DI* registers may be adjusted in the wrong direction. Use `STD`/`CLD` to set it to the direction you wish (CLD=forward/STD=backwards). In this case the code assumes forward movement so one should use `CLD`. More on this can be found in an [instruction set reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_29.html)

Your assembly code is set to compile and link assuming an origin point of 0x7C00 (via `ORG 0x7C00`). Your code that accesses variables like *msg* and *bootdev* will be made with the assumption that their memory address will be absolute within the segment (*DS*). This means that if you have an invalid *DS* segment then you could be addressing variables, data, and labels at the wrong locations. As an example:

```
mov [bootdev], dl
```

has an implicit reference to *DS* and is equivalent to addressing it with an explicit *DS* segment:

```
mov [ds:bootdev], dl
```

If *DS* has some random value in it then you'll likely be accessing memory in places you don't expect. For some environments *DS* might just be zero so your code will work.

How do you know which segment to use? The bootloader is loaded by the BIOS at physical memory 0x0000:0x7C00(segment:offset) . Your origin point (Set with `ORG` directive) matches the offset so that means in your case *DS* should be set to zero.

In your code *ES* should also be set to zero. The reason is that [INT 0x13 AH=0x02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D02h:_Read_Sectors_From_Drive) (disk read) says:

> ES:BX  Buffer Address Pointer

Imagine if *ES* is set to random garbage, the disk read will likely read into memory you didn't intend. So just like *DS*, *ES* must also be set. You've written your bootloader and kernel in the same file with the origin point of 0x7C00 so again you just need to use an *ES* segment set to zero.

When setting up your stack you can set *ES* and *DS* appropriately.

```
mov ax, 0x0000            ; Set up the stack
mov ss, ax                ; Is this done correctly?
mov sp, 0x7C00            ; (I dont quite understand)
mov ds, ax                ; Set DS to 0 because that is what your code needs
mov es, ax                ;     ES the same as DS.
cld                       ; Read my tip #2
```

You did ask if you set your stack properly. There is nothing wrong with it. Your instructions effectively set up a a stack that grows downward from `0x0000:0x7C00` just below the area occupied by your bootloader. That leaves about 27kb (`0x7C00-0x1000`) of stack space. 4k is plenty for BIOS calls and your current code. The first `0x1000` of memory are generally for interrupt table/BIOS data area etc.

One other bug I noticed in your code was when you try to reset the disk drive:

```
int 0x10                  ; Set video mode
int 0x13                  ; Reset the drive
```

You set *AX* to zero above these 2 lines. [INT 0x10 AH=0x00](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/74/0.html) (set video mode) has the side effect of returning information in *AX*. Since *AX* can be clobbered your call to [INT 0x13 AH=0x00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D00h:_Reset_Disk_Drive) will likely be wrong. You need to clear *AH* (or all of *AX*) prior to calling `int 0x13` to reset the drive. The code should look like:

```
int 0x10                  ; Set video mode
xor ax,ax                 ; clear AX (AH=0)
int 0x13                  ; Reset the drive
```

There is a minor issue at the top of your program and would likely only be a problem if you put this bootloader on a properly formatted FAT12 disk image and tried to mount it in your OS. You have:

```
jmp boot_sector
;------------------------------    
OEMLabel            db "FLOPPYDR"
```

The disk structure you have within your bootloader should have `OEMLabel` starting from the 4th byte. `jmp boot_sector` could be encoded as a 2 or 3 byte instruction by NASM. Use `short` to force a 2 byte encoding followed by a `NOP` (1 byte instruction). This will place `OEMLabel` at the 4th byte in the file. It could look like this:

```
jmp short boot_sector
nop
;------------------------------    
OEMLabel            db "FLOPPYDR"
```

Alternatively you can encode a `JMP` that may be 2 or 3 bytes when encoded and pad it with `NOP` if necessary using NASM's `TIMES` directive so that `OEMLabel` always starts at the 4th byte:

```
jmp boot_sector
times 3-($-$$) nop
;------------------------------    
OEMLabel            db "FLOPPYDR"
```

A trick to avoid using `hexedit` to manually insert the bootloader code at the beginning of a disk image is to use `dd`. You can use `dd` to overwrite the first 1024 bytes and keep the rest intact. Try `dd if=boot.bin of=floppy.flp bs=512 count=2 conv=notrunc` . This should open up *floppy.flp* write 2 512 byte sectors containing the 1024 bytes from *boot.bin* without truncating the file (*conv=notrunc*)

Comment: In NASM syntax the `ds:` override belongs within the brackets, like in `mov [ds:bootdev], dl`. However, this is not entirely correct as an equivalent, because specifying this override will make NASM actually emit the unneeded override prefix byte.

Comment: The `jmp boot_sector` is a short jump (though specifying this explicitly as `jmp short boot_sector` is better), so it is a 2-byte instruction, not as you wrote 3-byte. To start the OEM ID in the 4th byte, the 1st and 2nd (`jmp short`) and 3rd (`nop`) bytes have to be used.

Comment: @ecm The DS: being inside the brackets is correct (I fixed that), however I wasn't going for instruction encoding being the same but to point out that there is an implicit DS as many people have no idea that there is an implicit segment on every memory address in 16/32 bit code.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify that the `[var]` address is equivalent to *addressing* `[ds:var]`, but without the "could have been written". By the way, your last edit changed the `DS:[` to `[fd:` ?

Comment: @ecm : 4:30 am and typing in the dark with eyes half open. FD is DS when your fingers are shifted left by one and you don't notice.

Answer (score 2):

When a bootloader is started the contents of almost all registers (including segment registers) is "undefined". The only register that actually does have a known value is DL (which contains the BIOS' drive number for the disk).

All instructions that refer to memory use an implied or explicit segment register. For example, both `mov [bootdev], dl` and `lodsb` rely on the (implied) DS segment register, which is never set and is still undefined.

Like all undefined values, it's possible (due to pure luck) for them to be a value that makes things work by accident. Your code would work if the BIOS happened to leave the value 0x0000 in DS.